# T-SQL: How to query/view/check/monitor the data in the temp tables/table variables used in SP (stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, debugging, stored-procedures, temp-tables

For those familiar with SSIS, in SSIS there is a data Viewer which can be connected to the data-flow between 2 data-flow component which during exeuction shows the data flowing from one component to the other.

I would like to have the same possibility when developing or troubleshooting/step-by-step debugging  SPs.

e.g. right now, I am Troubleshooting a SP with more than 2500 lines of Code, making use of many temp tables and table variables.

One possibility I know is to change local temp tables and table variables to global temp tables so to query them from another query tab ie from another session and to change them back once done.

Does anybody know whether there is any other simpler approach?

Comment: As an advice, try to avoid godlike SPs when coding.

Answer (score 1):

PRINT wont output anything until the proc has finished. In circumstances like yours you can make use of [RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1660/using-the-nowait-option-with-the-sql-server-raiserror-statement/) which will output a message immediately.

e.g.

```
RAISERROR ('Now that''s what I call a message!', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can break the code in batches, you can use `PRINT` statements throughout.

Simple Example... run this and be sure you have clicked on the Messages tab as soon as you execute.

```
select 1 as 'a' into #t
print '#t table pouplated'
go

--simulate some heavy queries taking some time
waitfor delay '00:00:05'
select 2 as b into #t2

print '#t2 table pouplated'
go
```

SQL Server [also has a debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/transact-sql-debugger?view=sql-server-2017)

Lastly... at parts throughout the procedure, you could update a table with the status, similar to the print message, so that you can query it whenever you want. This would eliminate the need to break things up into batches... I'd add a flag for this so that you can simply flip it to 0 when you are done debugging so the insert isn't executed.

```
declare @logToTable bit = 1

select 1 as 'a' into #t

if @logToTable = 1
begin
   insert into logTable (status_msg, log_date)
   values
   ('#t populated',getdate())
end

--simulate some heavy queries taking some time

waitfor delay '00:00:05'


select 2 as b into #t2

if @logToTable = 1
begin
   insert into logTable (status_msg, log_date)
   values
   ('#t2 populated',getdate())
end
```

Answer (score 0):

And the solution is:

https://github.com/FilipDeVos/sp_select

Great stuff!